# 301 redirection querystring to clean URL

Tags: regex, apache2

I have a new version of the deuxia.com website

The site used URLs with Querystring, now "clean" URLs.

To avoid 404 errors and not lose SEO, I would like to redirect in the .htaccess (apache server 2.4)

Example old URL
https://www.deuxia.com/detail-produit-immobilier.php?rechercheRef=SO600

Desired URL
https://www.deuxia.com/detail-annonce-immobilier/SO600

SO600 is the product reference (dynamic)

Merci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # OTHER CODE

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^rechercheRef=(\w+)
    RewriteRule ^detail-produit-immobilier\.php$ /detail-annonce-immobilier/%1? [R=301,L]

    # OTHER CODE
</IfModule>
```